# PTIJ: Who should pay for Uber rides: the child or the parent?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There's a big machlokes in *shas* about ridesharing. Namely, who pays for it: the mother (parent) or the child?

[Yevamos 78a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.78a.16-17?lang=bi)

> "עובר ירך אמו"  *vs*   "עובר **לאו** ירך אמו"
>
> "Uber should be charged to the parent" *vs* "Uber should  **NOT** be charged to the parent"

Thoughts on how we might *pasken*?
Would the *halacha* be similar  or different for Lyft?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: My Hebrew is lacking, here. The word ירך  means "charged to"??

Comment: @DanF it does not- literally means "thigh" #sorryaboutthat

Comment: Oh well, then, I really don't understand the question enough to give it a decent answer.

Comment: What's the source  of עובר לאו ירך אמו

Comment: @larry909 Chullin 58a seems to be the only time when the discussion comes up that both sides are presented.

Comment: @larry909 good point- just added

Comment: @DonielF OP posted a different place

Comment: @larry909 I stand corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the one who pays is the one who does the action of making the arrangements, as we hold עובר לעשייתן, that the Uber goes to the one who does the work for it.

Comment: So...the driver?

Comment: @rosends gevaldik- shkoyach!

Answer (score 4):

This question is asked as long ago as the Gemara:
(Sanhedrin 57b):

> משום רבי ישמעאל אמרו אף על העוברין מאי טעמיה דרבי ישמעאל דכתיב (בראשית ט, ו) שופך דם האדם באדם דמו ישפך איזהו אדם שהוא באדם הוי אומר זה עובר שבמעי אמו- it was said in the name of rabbi yishmael: why even the Uber users? As it says, ‘the one who pours money of man, his own money will be poured in man’. Who is this ‘man whose will be poured in man’? That who Uber’s in his mother’s stomach”
>   We see from here, that one who Uber’s in his mother’s stomach, I.e. the son, he ends up pouring his money into man (gives his money to the cabby) [דם in this instance means money, like דמים, not blood]

The achronim talk about this as well:
 (shita mekubetzes Bava Basra 139b)

> עובר בן הוא לא עדיף- Uber, a son is not preferred
>   We see then, that the shita mekubetzes argues with the Gemara! The chachmas Adam solves this contradiction:
>   (chachmas adam 28)
>
> עובר בן ח' או בן ט'- Uber, [only] an 8 or 9 year old son
>   Only from 8 or 9 years old does a son need to pay for his parents Uber.

The Gemara is talking about a child under the age of 8, who is not expected to finance his parents Uber. The shita mekubetzes is talking about an older child, from 8/9 and up, who is expected to finance his parents Uber.
This is how we pasken (as there are no other sources that talk about it).
As for Lyft, it says in herchev davar al Bereshit (27):

> מצות כיבוד אב כמו שאירע ליפת. - it is a mitzva of kibbud av va’em like what happened with Lyft.

We see from here that we learn Hilchos kibbud av va’em for Uber from Lyft! So for sure the Halachos will be the same!

Answer (score 3):

While [rosends's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100761/) covers Uber, what about Lyft? Berachos 40a says:

> אמר רב חסדא קיתון לפת
>
> Rav Chisda said, a kid on the Lyft.

What does this mean? Does this mean that the kid pays for it, or that the parent pays for the Lyft on top of the kid? On 43a, the Gemara elaborates:

> הסבה לפת מהניא
>
> The grandfather [for the] Lyft helps.

This clearly implies that the elder generation pays for it, and so the parent pays for the child.